# Wordpress Customizing /inc/customizer.php in Child Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

Customizing *`/inc/customizer.php`* in the child theme is not overriding the parent theme.

We are trying to over ride max item count in child theme & changing in parent

theme file works. But making the same change in a child theme’s

*`/inc/customizer.php.php`* does not work, nor does copying the function to the

child theme’s functions.php file

**Parent Theme Code**

```
$wp_customize->add_control(
            new Mediapap_Customize_Repeatable_Control(
                $wp_customize,
                'mediapap_social_profiles',
                array(
                    'label'         => esc_html__('Socials', 'mediapap'),
                    'description'   => '',
                    'section'       => 'mediapap_social',
                    'live_title_id' => 'network', // apply for unput text and textarea only
                    'title_format'  => esc_html__('[live_title]', 'mediapap'), // [live_title]
                    'max_item'      => 5, 
                    'fields'    => array(
                        'network'  => array(
                            'title' => esc_html__('Social network', 'mediapap'),
                            'type'  =>'text',
                        ),
                        'icon'  => array(
                            'title' => esc_html__('Icon', 'mediapap'),
                            'type'  =>'icon',
                        ),
                        'link'  => array(
                            'title' => esc_html__('URL', 'mediapap'),
                            'type'  =>'text',
                        ),
                    ),

                )
            )
        );
```

Comment: you need to override the file which includes this inc/customizer.php also share us the theme structure.

Comment: @TajKhan this inc/customizer.php is only available in following file     inc/customizer.php               // Load custom controls.
 require get_template_directory() . '/inc/customizer-controls.php';